# Laravel : On 5.5 validation message not showing on view.blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Validation not showing any message on view page. I just can't figure out.

My controller code

```
 public function save(Request $request) {
    try {
        $file = $request->file('flag_image');
        $this->validate($request, Country::rules()); // checking validation

        /*Image Upload code*/
        If(Input::hasFile('flag_image')){
            $file = Input::file('flag_image');
            $destinationPath = public_path(). '/images/admin/country/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image = time().$filename;
            $file->move($destinationPath, $image);
            $imgpath = 'images/admin/country/'.$image;
        }
        if($file !="") {
            $request->merge(['flag_image' => $imgpath]);
        }
        /*Image Upload code end*/

        $country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($file !="") {
            $country->flag_image = $imgpath;
            $country->save();
        }

        if($country !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('lists-country')->with('success', trans('Country data added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
    }
}
```

Here is my model code for validation check :

```
 public static function rules() {
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'short_name' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(",", Country::STATUSES)
    ];
}
```

On view page didn' get any validation message : On my view

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div> @endif
```

Also added in a app/exceptions/handler.php file code

```
 protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
    \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
];
```

Not working at all.what am i missing ?

Comment: You need to flash the errors before you redirect. You are losing the errors in between.

Comment: @btl what shd i add ?

Comment: Read here on how to flash to session https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
@if (session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
           <li>{{ session('error') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
@endif
```

In this way you can access only the key, that has been set by **with** methods

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$this->validate($request, Country::rules());
```

To:

```
$request->validate(Country::rules());
```